# Eclipse, cannot install PHP PDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I am having problem to install this plug in: PHP development kit for Eclipse Juno

I am using the latest Juno Eclipse, I use the menu help -> Install Software -> I add the link http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

I see all the availables packages, I choose PHP Development toolkit ( under the Web, XML, Java EE packages )

it trying to install, after very long minutes, I got this error, at about 49%:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Failed to transfer artifact packed: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xerces,2.9.0.v201101211617.
Retry another mirror
Artifact not found: ftp://mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn/mirror/eclipse/releases/juno/201206270900/plugins/org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v201101211617.jar.pack.gz.
ftp://mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn/mirror/eclipse/releases/juno/201206270900/plugins/org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v201101211617.jar.pack.gz
Retry another mirror
Artifact not found: http://espelhos.edugraf.ufsc.br/eclipse//releases/juno/201206270900/plugins/org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v201101211617.jar.pack.gz.
http://espelhos.edugraf.ufsc.br/eclipse//releases/juno/201206270900/plugins/org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v201101211617.jar.pack.gz
Retry another mirror
```

......

I tried out removing the firewalls, move the eclipse folder around, retry the installations, downloading another eclipse 64/32 Juno package, everything without success

I tried another repository: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/nightly without success as well

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on Windows 8, running Eclipse as an administrator solved it for me (right click the executable and Run as administrator).